# Yii: how to define partials for layout in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, yii

In Rails it's easy:

View has:

`<% content_for :sidebar do %>
... sidebar HTML ...
<% end %>`

Layout has:

`<%= yield :sidebar %>`

Can I do same in Yii?

**UPDATE:** How can use both dynamic header, content and footer in main.php layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `public $sidebar` in your base Controller component. Then you can assign to `$this->sidebar` in your views or controllers and retrieve `$this->sidebar` in your layouts. You should also look into [`renderPartial()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) which can be used in layouts, controllers, and views to render partial HTML content (content without layout). e.g. `$this->renderPartial('/some/view')`

Answer (score 4):

View has:

```
<?php $this->beginClip('sidebar'); ?>
Hi there!
<?php $this->endClip(); ?>
```

Layout has:

```
<?= $this->clips['sidebar'] ?>
```

For more look at CController docs.

But in all fairness, this is the wrong way to do sidebars.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, in yii you can render partial content using renderPartial(),

you can have a look on renderpartial()  [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail)

You can use it as `$this->renderPartial('/folder/view')`